# can't Load local files dynamically in react js

Tags: reactjs

I want to load some local images dynamically in my app. I have a json with records like

> {name: image12, poster: 'image1.jpg'}, {name: image13, poster: 'image2.jpg'}

I have a folder with many images like **'image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg'**. When I try to render the json record i put 
`<img src={'./image/image1.jpg'}/>` but it is not working.

```
[![import React from 'react';

const Poster = (props) => {
    return(
        <div className="individual-poster">
            <h2>{props.postData.name}</h2>
            <img src={'./Slices/'+props.postData["poster"]} width="100px" height="100px"/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

image is not even listing in the source list also.

[image]

Comment: please share the code

Comment: By "local" you mean in a folder of your computer ? Or in a public folder of your http server ?
Also what do you see in the browser developer tools (console / network) ?

Comment: @karthik. i share code also. please check.

Comment: show console/network calls. replace this picture you have uploaded. it doesn't help

Comment: @Ricovitch i put image in a folder of my app.

Comment: also, can you show how you are providing the postData prop attribute to this component

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay i add network call image also. "content": [
        {
          "name": "img1",
          "poster-image": "image1.jpg"
        },
        {
          "name": "img2",
          "poster-image": "image2.jpg"
        },]
please check

Comment: two things, can check whether console has any error and can you locate the dom and check what source is being provided to the img tag?

Comment: is this app created using `create-react-app` and if so, is the images in the public folder?

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay there is no error in the console. <img src="./Slices/image1.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">

Comment: @illiteratewriter. i create using create-react-app. it is in the public folder

Comment: You need to use either absolute URL's or use `import`

Comment: @Abinthaha i need to generate the img tag based the json data. so i cant use the import.  how to set absolute path.

Comment: <img src ="http://localhost:3000/details/img/myImage.png" />

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644265/correct-path-for-img-on-react-js

Comment: @Abinthaha i tried that also but not working. please check the first image. localhost does not have the image

Comment: Since your images are in `public` folder, could you try this?
<img src={window.location.origin + '/img/myImage.png'} />

Comment: @Abinthaha. sorry not working. my image inside my app folder..   src/image1.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know path images then your json object you trying to map must be somewhat similar to this:

```
const obj = [
    {"name":"Chrysanthemum","path":require('./Chrysanthemum.jpg')}, //this will work
    {"name":"Desert","path":'./Desert.jpg'}, //will not work
]
```

`require` your path to images must be inside require mehtod.
Use like considering json obj file exported as default in same directory with file name `imagesJson`.

```
import imagArray from './images';
```

map like this

```
imagArray.map((m)=>{
            return <div>
               {m.name}
                 <img src={m.path}/>
            </div>
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you created you react app with create-react-app then you can import image  variable and later use it multiple time.

```
import logo from './logo.png' // relative path to image 

class App extends Component { 
    render() { 
        return ( 
            <img src={logo} alt={"logo"}/> 
        )  
    }
}
```

or you can directly specify image relative path.

```
<img src ="http://localhost:3000/img/foo.png" />
<img src="/details/img/bar.png" />
```

In your question for use images from array

```
const images = [{
    name: 'image12',
    path: 'image1.jpg'
}, {
    name: 'image13',
    path: 'image2.jpg'
}];

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div>
             <img src={logo} alt={"logo"}/>
            {images.map((img) => <img src={img.post} alt={img.name} />)}
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```